# NAN, como resultado de uma função

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código javascript muito simples, porém, gostaria de saber pq o resultado de retorno está sendo NAN? O HTML:

```
<label for="pretensaoMes">Pretensão ao Mês</label>
<input type="text" id="pretensaoMes">
<label for="diasPorMes">Dias por Mês</label>
<input type="text" id="diasPorMes">
<label for="horasPorDia">Horas por Dia</label>
<input type="text" id="horasPorDia">

<button id="btn">Clique</button>
<p id="result">Nenhum resultado</p>
```

E o JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var PM = document.getElementById("pretensaoMes");
var PMINT = PM.value;
var pm = parseInt().PMINT;
var DM = document.getElementById("diasPorMes");
var DMINT = DM.value;
var dm = parseInt().DMINT;
var HD = document.getElementById("horasPorDia");
var HDINT = HD.value;
var hd = parseInt().HDINT;
var horaTrabalho = pm + dm + hd;
var tanto = horaTrabalho;

var result = document.getElementById("result");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    result.innerHTML = tanto;

})
```

Comment: O JS é executado depois do carregamento dá pagina ? Que seria através do `onload` do `<body>` ou sendo colocado no fim do `<body>`

Comment: Dentro do <body></body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O obter dos valores dos inputs está a ser feito antes sequer do usuário os introduzir. Apenas os deve obter quando o botão é clicado ou seja, no evento de `click`. Isto refere-se ao `.value` e não especificamente ao `getElementById`, assumindo que este JS apenas corre após os elementos terem sido todos carregados.

O `parseInt` tem de levar como parâmetro o valor a converter para inteiro:

```
var dm = parseInt(DMINT); //em vez de var dm = parseInt().DMINT;
```

Pode reorganizar assim:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var PM = document.getElementById("pretensaoMes");
var DM = document.getElementById("diasPorMes");
var HD = document.getElementById("horasPorDia");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var PMINT = PM.value;
    var pm = parseInt(PMINT);
    var DMINT = DM.value;
    var dm = parseInt(DMINT);
    var HDINT = HD.value;
    var hd = parseInt(HDINT);
    var horaTrabalho = pm + dm + hd;
    var tanto = horaTrabalho;
    result.innerHTML = tanto;
});
```

```html
<label for="pretensaoMes">Pretensão ao Mês</label>
<input type="text" id="pretensaoMes">
<label for="diasPorMes">Dias por Mês</label>
<input type="text" id="diasPorMes">
<label for="horasPorDia">Horas por Dia</label>
<input type="text" id="horasPorDia">

<button id="btn">Clique</button>
<p id="result">Nenhum resultado</p>
```

Sugiro no entanto que simplifique, fazendo a busca do `.value` e convertendo com o `parseInt` na mesma instrução. Mesmo a variável `horaTrabalho` não é necessária uma vez que passa logo de seguida o seu valor para a variável `tanto`

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var PM = document.getElementById("pretensaoMes");
var DM = document.getElementById("diasPorMes");
var HD = document.getElementById("horasPorDia");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var pm = parseInt(PM.value);
    var dm = parseInt(DM.value);
    var hd = parseInt(HD.value);

    var tanto = pm + dm + hd;
    result.innerHTML = tanto;
});
```

```html
<label for="pretensaoMes">Pretensão ao Mês</label>
<input type="text" id="pretensaoMes">
<label for="diasPorMes">Dias por Mês</label>
<input type="text" id="diasPorMes">
<label for="horasPorDia">Horas por Dia</label>
<input type="text" id="horasPorDia">

<button id="btn">Clique</button>
<p id="result">Nenhum resultado</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isto:

```
var pm = parseInt().PMINT;
```

isto

```
var dm = parseInt().DMINT;
```

E isto

```
var dm = parseInt().HDINT;
```

Simplesmente não fazem sentido, o `.PMINT`, `.DMINT` e `.HDINT` não são a mesma coisa que `PMINT`, `DMINT` e `HDINT`.

Ao tentar acessar o retorno com ponto `.` de `parseInt` que é uma propriedade NaN, você tentará acessar propriedades internas dele, mas não faz muito sentido.

O correto provavelmente deveria ser:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    var PM = document.getElementById("pretensaoMes");
    var PMINT = PM.value;
    var pm = parseInt(PMINT);
    var DM = document.getElementById("diasPorMes");
    var DMINT = DM.value;
    var dm = parseInt(DMINT);
    var HD = document.getElementById("horasPorDia");
    var HDINT = HD.value;
    var hd = parseInt(HDINT);
    var horaTrabalho = pm + dm + hd;
    var tanto = horaTrabalho;

    result.innerHTML = tanto;

});
```

```html
<label for="pretensaoMes">Pretensão ao Mês</label>
<input type="text" id="pretensaoMes">
<label for="diasPorMes">Dias por Mês</label>
<input type="text" id="diasPorMes">
<label for="horasPorDia">Horas por Dia</label>
<input type="text" id="horasPorDia">

<button id="btn">Clique</button>
<p id="result">Nenhum resultado</p>
```

Comment: Valew man, deu certo aqui, Obrigado!